# Arduino Motion Sensor Light timer

Tags: c++, arduino, arduino-c++

currently trying to make a motion sensor light that i can turn on and off with sensor detection but also have auto turn off after lets say 15 minutes if left on.

I've got it so i can turn it off and on now using motion but not sure how to have it auto turn off after a set time since delay blocks me from turning it off with motion if i try using that.

I'm thinking I'll have to use the millis function? but not sure where to start and feel like I've hit a wall so any guidance would be appreciated.

here's the code i have so far to have the sensor turn it off and on.

````
int pir = 2;
int val;
int state = 0;

void setup() {
pinMode(led, OUTPUT);
pinMode(pir, INPUT);
}

void loop() {

val = digitalRead(pir);

if (val == HIGH)
{
if (state == 0)
{
state = 1;
digitalWrite(led, HIGH);
delay (4000);
}
else {
state = 0;
digitalWrite(led, LOW);
delay (4000);
}
}
}```
````

Answer (score 0):

have a global variable `unsigned long sleep_start;`. Set `sleep_start = 0` everytime you turn the LED off and`sleep_start = millis();` every time the LED goes on.

Then at the start of loop():

```
if (sleep_start > 0 && millis() > sleep_start + 15 * 60 * 1000) {
    // it is now over 15 minutes since the LED went on
    // do whatever you want - turn LED off and set state = 0 ?
}
```

I not you have your actions and state tied together - i.e. you set the state and then turn on/off the LED at the same time. Much better to set the state separately and then set the LED based on the state.

```
void loop() 
{
   unsigned long now = millis();
   val = digitalRead(pir);
   bool state_changed = false;
   if (val == HIGH)
   {
       if (state == 0)
           state = 1;
       else
           state = 0;

       state_changed = true;
   }

   // state was not changed by the sensor so look for timeout
   if (!state_changed)
   {
       if (state == 1 && now > sleep_start + 15 * 60 * 1000)
       {
           state = 0;
           state_changed = true;
       }
   }

   if (state_changed)
   {
       switch(state) {
           case 0: digitalWrite(led, LOW);
                   break;
           case 1: digitalWrite(led, HIGH);
                   sleep_start = now;
                   break;
       }
   }
   delay(4000);
}
```